# when react-native downloading gradle , I get PKIX error and response code 403

Tags: react-native, gradle

I try run-android on react-native.
when the step dowloading gradle, I get the PKIX error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I try the solution below, but still don't work.

1. dowload the .cer from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
   and import it to "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib\security\cacerts" by keytool
2. gradle-wrapper.properties -> change url from **https** to **http**
   After changed, I get **HTTP response code: 403**

Answer (score 0):

Check which JDK / JRE gradle is using as this is often confusing. If necessary, you can specify the trustore by the system property javax.net.ssl.trustStore.

javax.net.ssl.trustStore is the location of the Java keystore file containing the collection of CA certificates trusted by this application process.
On Windows, the specified pathname must use forward slashes, /, in place of backslashes, .

I had the same PKIX problem, and importing the certificate partially resolved it.
However, I had to add the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore java parameter in the gradlew.bat file of my project :

1. download the certificate from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and import it to "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib\security\cacerts" by keytool
2. Edit gradlew.bat in your project and add "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Path\to\lib\security\cacerts" to the DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).